# What happens if a bounty is started again and but no correct answer gets posted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, bounty

I want to know on case regarding bounty which is not mentioned in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

- OP starts a bounty with 100 reputation to bring attention to their question.
- OP gets answers, but isn't satisfied and doesn't accept any of them.
- When the grace period ends, the highest voted answer receives the half of the bounty reputation (50).
- OP starts bounty again with 250 reputation.
- OP receives no new answers, and the existing answers aren't edited.

So, when the grace period ends, who gets the new bounty? Or does the bounty get back to the OP?

Check for this question: [Slick animate when moving past the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834365/slick-animate-when-moving-past-the-center/39018909#39018909)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at each time the bounty is posted separately.  If, when the second bounty is posted, no new answers are added and the bounty is not manually awarded the bounty ends and no one gets an award.  If the OP had accepted a answer it would have been awarded to that answer.  If the OP had manually awarded the bounty to an answer they would get the full amount.  If a new answer was posted and it got the required number of up votes then it would get half(split among any other qualifying answers) the bounty.

In this particular case since none of that happened no one gets anything and the 250 rep is gone.

Answer (score 2):

From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) in the Help Center (emphasis mine):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

So, if after starting the bounty there were no new answers with a score of at least 2, the bounty won't be awarded to anyone.

You can see in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38834365/revisions) that this is what happened in the question you linked:

[image]